# How can I get the microphone input in python?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I want to make a Python program where microphone audio input is received.

I already tried pyaudio but I can't understand how it works.

Answer (score 3):

There is this module called `gTTS` that you can use instead.

> The `get_audio` function will be able to detect a users voice, translate the audio to text and return it to us. It will even wait until the user is speaking to start translating/recording the audio

Here's a complete example on `Getting user input` using the `get_audio` function.

```
def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

    return said
```